# How do I upload pictures as an album to Facebook, directly from Pictures?

Tags: pictures, facebook

Facebook is integrated with the OS. I can upload and share a single photo with my friends from the context menu when i am in the Picutres. Installing the Facebook app seems to be a moot point for me, since FB is already integrated.

So, I have two questions related to Facebook:

1. How do I create an album and upload pictures in bulk?
2. I can see the notifications, chat and newsfeed, but there isn't seem to be a way to receive/read the FB messages. Can some one please let me know whether i am missing something or this is a feature that will be added in the future?

I am using a Lumia 900 running Windows 7.5.

Comment: Please ask separate questions in separate questions, thank you. :)

Comment: I asked both the questions in the same thread, because both of them were related to FB, my mistake. Will definitely create separate questions in future.

Comment: No problem, it would benefit people searching for it. Also, you might want to try to see what the Facebook application can do for you; you can always uninstall it later. My short answer is that "it is not currently possible so you'll need to find a workaround"; but perhaps someone else has an idea, or knows of a user-made application that might be able to pull this off. From a developer standpoint; I don't know whether the Windows Phone supports selecting multiple images, to be honest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I create an album and upload pictures in bulk?

This is not really a task for a Phone; the only approach is to upload your photos one-by-one, and then attempt to move them all to the same album. A bulk way would be to get them on your computer (through SkyDrive or Zune) and then upload them from there.

Perhaps Windows Phone 8 might bring this; you could try to [suggest that feature here](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions), as well as for Facebook to simplify their Windows Phone application.

> I can see the notifications, chat and newsfeed, but there isn't seem to be a way to receive/read the FB messages.

You can receive these in the Messaging Hub if you have added the Facebook account to your phone.

Comment: does he want to know about chat message or private message? I know if facebook you can see them in the same place, but private message don't show in your message hub. At least they don't for me. Even with facebook chat enabled on my phone.

Comment: Not sure, but he accepted my answer so I guess it is OK? If not, your comment would help him... @Joe

Comment: My phone behaves like Joe's, no messages in the hub (even with chat enabled).

Comment: @Louis: Yeah, only Chat appears there, no the private stuff. I know, but we were uncertain if that was what the OP was looking for. He didn't specify whether it was chat or private messages...

Answer (score 0):

In order for your Facebook chat to work, you & the other user will need to have your Windows Live account linked up to their facebook. Facebook treats private messages like chat now, so they both will be sent to your messaging hub as if it were a live chat.

When someone sends me a message from facebook (chat or PM) it comes through the messaging hub, if someone writes on my wall or comments it goes to my ME tile.

Here is an excellent post on how to setup your facebook chat. http://www.mobilityminded.com/13066/how-to-activate-facebook-chat-in-messaging-on-windows-phone-mango-update/

Source: Mobility Minded